# Invalid GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

I have the following GraphQL schema:

```
type User {
  id: String!
  email: String
}

input CreateUserDto {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

input CredentialsDto {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

type CreateUserResponseDto {
  id: String!
}

type TokenResponseDto {
  token: String!
}

type Mutation {
  signup(input: CreateUserDto!): CreateUserResponseDto!
}

type Query {
  user(id: Int!): User

  auth {
    login(credentials: CredentialsDto!): TokenResponseDto
  }
}
```

And for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Expected :, found {

GraphQL request (13:8)
12: 
13:   auth {
           ^
14:     login(credentials: CredentialsDto!): TokenResponseDto
```

If I will add `:` after the `auth` attribute than I will get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {

GraphQL request (13:9)
12: 
13:   auth: {
            ^
14:     login(credentials: CredentialsDto!): TokenResponseDto

What am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't utilize anonymous objects when defining your schema. You have to create a separate type for the `auth` field to return:

```
type Auth {
  login(credentials: CredentialsDto!): TokenResponseDto
}

type Query {
  user(id: Int!): User
  auth: Auth
}
```

Assuming you are using `apollo-server` or `graphql-tools`, your resolvers then need to look something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: () => {
      // TODO: resolve field
    }
    auth: () => ({}) // return an empty object
  },
  Auth: {
    login: () => {
      // TODO: resolve field  
    }
  }
}
```

The thing to remember is that the resolvers object is just a map of type names, with each type name mapping to another map of field names.

Comment: Yes, just figured this out. But how can I then resolve the login field?

Comment: I am getting this error: Query.login defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Comment: As the error shows, you don't have a field called `login` on your `Query` type, so you can't have a resolver for it. See my edit.